# Cross reference matrix in Excel

Tags: excel, reporting

I have a two column list:

```
SystemA, tableA
SystemA, tableB
SystemA, tableC
SystemA, tableD
SystemB, tableA
SystemB, tableC
SystemB, tableD
SystemC, tableA
```

I need to generate a cross reference matrix listing tables (no dups) and which systems reference them.

Here is what it should look like:

```
        SystemA  SystemB  SystemC  
tableA     x        x         x  
tableB     x  
tableC     x        x  
tableD     x        x
```

Is this something that can be done in Excel or do I have to write code to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a simple pivot table. Make some search on google. 
Following wizard is very simple. You have just to drag fields in the right place (table on row field and system on both column field and data field).

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked like a champ.